# ::ng-deep is affecting other components in material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I need a changes in mat-menu-content for specific component but its affecting every other components too and i tried **view encapsulation** and **:host ::ng-deep** but there's no changes

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-menu-content {
            padding-top: 8px !important;
            padding-bottom: 8px !important;
            display: flex !important;
          }
```

I need like this in mat-menu-content
[image]

But its affecting others components too like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

can you please make one tag in html and set "maincss" class after in that tag add your html code.

also write your cass like this :

```
.maincss{
.mat-menu-content {
            padding-top: 8px !important;
            padding-bottom: 8px !important;
            display: flex !important;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the use of `::ng-deep` beacause actually can affect other styles since it can go over the encapsulation of the components and change styles. Consider instead using the `@Input()` properties that `<mat-menu>` provides to modify the styles: `backdropClass` and `panelClass`

This is a simple example that you could adapt to your code according to your requirements:

```
<mat-menu backdropClass="my-menu-backdrop" panelClass="my-menu-panel">
  <menu mat-menu-item>Profile</menu>
  <menu mat-menu-item>Account</menu>
</mat-menu>
```

Then in your global styles define your classes with your styles:

```
.my-menu-backdrop {
  // Put your styles for menu backdrop
}

.my-menu-panel {
  // Put your styles for menu panel
}
```

There are more properties that could be useful for you.
For more information about this props you could check the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api)